# Qt Error: Can't declared multiple mainwindows in main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt

In "main.cpp":

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mainwindow_1.h"
```

And I code in main.cpp:

```
MainWindow *mainWin_1 = new MainWindow;
MainWindow_1 *mainWin_2 = new MainWindow_1;
```

I'm already declared `MainWindow` and `MainWindow_1` in "mainwindow.h" and "mainwindow_1.h". They are both `QMainWindow`. But when I debug, I got an error that said "MainWindow_1 was not declared in this scope".

When I changed:

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "mainwindow_1.h"
```

into

```
 #include "mainwindow_1.h"
 #include "mainwindow.h"
```

I got the error "MainWindow was not declared in this scope".

Can I only include one mainwindow? How can I get two `QMainwindow` in main.cpp without error?

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <ctime>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT;

    public:
        MainWindow();
        ~MainWindow(); 
};
#endif
```

mainwindow_1.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <ctime>

class MainWindow_1 : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT;

    public:
        MainWindow_1();
        ~MainWindow_1(); 
};
#endif
```

Comment: Please show the two include files.

Comment: You can have two classes with different names that both extend `QMainWindow`, but you can't import two classes with the same name, no matter what they extend. QtCreator lets you choose the name of the class you are generating

Comment: Another thing, do "find in files" kind if text search for all the relevant symbols, and see if you have them wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have same include guard macro in both .h files.

So, change both the `#ifndef` and `#define` near beginning of one of the .h files to be different from the include guards of the other .h file.
For example change *mainwindow_1.h* to have this:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_1_H
#define MAINWINDOW_1_H
```

When you have same include guard macro, then the contents of the file included later will be skipped, and the class in it will be left undefined in that .cpp file.

One thing to keep in mind is, C++ include files are not like "import" or such of many other languages. `#include` just inserts contents of the other file into the compilation, same as if you copy-pasted it. Among other things, this means that later include file "sees" all macros defined in earlier include files, so include guards must have unique names.

Comment: Thanks, hyde. It's run.